# Updating or uninstalling applications as another user with Install Shield 2009

Tags: installshield

I have a MSI set up using install shield 2009 for my VB6.0 exe and it is working. The problem is if user A (1st user) has ran the setup to install the applications and we're trying to run the update using User B (2nd user). It doesn't allow us to do so. The same goes when we want to uninstall the app.

Could you please suggest if it is due to some restrictions that Windows has given or if not, how can we make another user to run the update or uninstall for a setup ran with someone else?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you installed as Per User instead of Per Machine.   If so, any install that User A performed will be out of scope of User B.   You'll have to uninstall and reinstall as PerMachine.

Note this is controlled by the ALLUSERS property and unles you have a specific need, the InstallShield  default value of "2" is probably what you should leave it at.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, let me try building the setup as per Machine and will be in touch again if I face any issue.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I tried to set ALLUSERS property to create a per machine setup, but wasn't able to find from where I can set this option in Installshield 2009. Could you please help me out where can I get the ALLUSERS property? Also, do I need to set this property to 1 to make it per machine context?

Comment: You set it in the PropertyManager. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx